# What happens in linear regression when observations are not independent in time

Tags: regression, linear-model, independence

Let's consider the example of whether a person's weight is correlated with their height (simple linear regression). What is the difference between running this correlation on the following two data sets?

**Measurements independent of time**
Randomly sample 100 people and record their weight and height.

**Measurements with time dependence**
Randomly sample 10 people, but record their weight and heights at 10 different times.

Comment: "*whether a person's weight is correlated with their weight*" --- I'm pretty sure that correlation is 1

Comment: seems related to this question as well http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89353/difference-between-iid-data-and-non-iid-data-for-a-simple-regression-problem

Answer (score 4):

When you have 100 observations sampled randomly, you can usually get all the nice properties assumed by OLS (e.g. strict exogeneity), which will allow you to declare Markov conditions and their consequences, such as BLUE (best linear unbiased estimator) and so on.

When your sample is not random anymore, strict exogeneity goes out the window. So, you start working around it with ergodicity, weak exogeneity etc., trying to bring back Markov conditions. The most you can do with OLS is get the asymptotic efficiency of OLS; small sample properties are useless. It's not BLUE anymore.

We usually assume ergodicity quite easily, but it's a *VERY* strong condition, in my opinion. In economics you observe only once, so you're assuming that if you kept collecting the data forever, then asymptotically probabilities will converge, etc. Having the most interesting series at quarterly frequency, this sounds ridiculous. Anyhow, we usually ignore these difficulties and go on with our lives.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit more on these Markov conditions? Is there some place where I can find out more about the "and so on" bit?

Comment: @Alex, Greene, Econometric Analysis, 7th ed, "Section 4.3 Finite Sample properties of least squares"